# PHP array has the same index for every element

Tags: php, arrays, firebird

I'm working on a program that prints the qualities of every individual in a team.

I have 3 tables:
The Teams table:

| TeamID |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |

The TeamPlayers table :

| PlayerID | Team |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 |
| 269 | 1 |
| 357 | 2 |

The program works like this: There is a textbox in the HTML page where the user is typing the ID of the team and the program outputs the members. The problem is that each player is stored in an array. and all have the same index:

```
$fetchPlayersSQL = "SELECT Player_ID
            FROM TeamPlayers
            WHERE Team = $TeamID;";
$fetchPlayers = ibase_query($dbConnection, $fetchPlayersSQL);
while ($row2 = ibase_fetch_object($fetchPlayers)) {
    $fetchPlayersArray = get_object_vars($row2);
    print_r($fetchPlayersArray);
}
```

Keep in mind $TeamID is the value introduced by the user in the HTML textbox.

Now, this program outputs this:

```
Array ( [Player_ID] => 2157 ) 

Array ( [Player_ID] => 734 ) 

Array ( [Player_ID] => 2160 ) 

Array ( [Player_ID] => 3744 ) 

Array ( [Player_ID] => 2166 )
```

(Keep in mind, 2157, 734, 2160, 3744 and 2166 are other players, there are a lot of them, but I listed only a few)

The problem is that I need every player to have their own index in the array, because I have to print their qualities

I really can't find where the problem comes from. Maybe I am using an incorrect method to select since there are more players in a team.

The 3rd table is just the qualities of every player

| PlayerID | Height | Weight | HairColor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 187 | 80 | black |
| 357 | 167 | 67 | grey |
| 269 | 182 | 95 | brown |

And the expected output is something like this:

The user enters 1 in the HTML textbox, Team 1 players are 100 and 269 so they should see:

```
Array ( [0] => 2157 )

Array ( [1] => 734  )
```

`echo $row2->Player_ID;` just prints their IDs, we have player 100 and 269 in the Team 1, and this prints 100269

Comment: What is your expected result ?

Comment: `I have 3 tables` where is the third?

Comment: Show us the complete output from the `print_r()`

Comment: Or a simple `echo $row2->Player_ID;`

Comment: The array you retrieve contains the value(s) of the column(s) you selected for a single row. If you want a single array with all rows, you need to create that yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might not be the most elegant solution, but you can always build that array yourself in a loop:

```
$a = array();
while ($row2 = ibase_fetch_object($fetchPlayers)) {
    $a[] = $row2->Player_ID;
}
print_r($a);
```

See if that works for you, I am not able to code at the moment.

Comment: At this point I don't even care about the elegance of the solution, THANK YOU. It works